# how to get file names and line numbers of file that I have modified in the past

Tags: git

Is there a git command to basically get a list of line numbers and filenames of files that I've made changes to. So that I can get a glimpse of changes I made in a certain location, e.g.

```
git check-last-change --dir=app/styles/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* using `git log` with the `-p` parameter will do what you want:

```
git log -p app/styles/
```

It will show the log of all files changed in the `app/styles` folder. The `-p` command tells it to show the changes introduced in each commit. The output looks like:

```
commit 3101fd9a2862de007f6b47b58adab2d1e29a722b
Author: David Zych <email>
Date:   Wed Apr 22 10:03:06 2015 -0700

    (Some commit message)

diff --git a/app/styles/site.css b/app/styles/site.css
index a2b5d32..3df6ed1 100644
--- a/app/styles/site.css
+++ b/app/styles/site.css
@@ -142,6 +142,11 @@ html {
+    color: red;
+    margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to limit the author to yourself, you can add the `--author` flag.

```
git log -p --author "David Zych" app/styles/
```

If you want to limit it to the most recent X changes, use the `-X` flag, where X is the number of changes you want to see. To see the most recent change:

```
git log -p -1 app/styles/
```

Comment: You may also want to use the `--author` flag.